# File path as PHP URL parameter

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that will be accepting several URL parameters, one of which is a local file path (c:\users\etc..).  Whenever this parameter is read in, PHP makes it into double backslashes (c:\users\etc..) which my upload code will not accept as a valid path.  What can I do here?

Thanks

-Jesse

Comment: At which point does it make them into double backslashes and at which point is the data rejected? Please show some code

Comment: I guess this is just basic escaping of characters caused by addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string() functions (or any similar). Try stripslashes() and see if they are being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, avoid accepting ***paths*** in query string for **security** reasons. You may want to set *include path* in php.ini file instead.

You can replace double backslashes with single ones like this:

```
$myvalue = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $original_path);
```

You specify `\` twice to actually escape it while replacing.

#### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/2SZ3EmMg)

Comment: Yea, I tried doing this.  But as you see, this statement is not properly escaped and is therefor not a valid statement.  Check out the code highlighting on the code you posted.

Comment: @jomille: Fixed that before seeing your comment :)

Comment: as the file path is passed via URL ($_GET), the f*cking `gpc_quotes` are involved. @jomille, check the output of `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc())`. If it's `1`, then you should `stripslashes()` on anything that comes via `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` or `$_REQUEST`. If it's `0`, then it's totally another issue so discard my comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
$newpath = str_replace("\\\\","\\",$oldpath);
```

or similary

```
$newpath = stripslashes($olpath);
```

note that the second one works depending on the `magin_quotes` setting in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a typical Magic Quotes-problem. You can [disable them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling) in different ways. As of PHP 5.3 they are deprecated und will be removed in PHP 6.